# How to set ButtonCell in ComboBox javafx?

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create a `ComboBox` that will display a preview of selected Image, but the `ComboBox` displays the string value instead.
I read many suggestions and I found out that I need to use the `setButtonCell()` method but I don't know how.

This is my code :

```
public class ContentTabPaneController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<CustomComboBox> cbxDevices;

    private final ObservableList<CustomComboBox> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        String smartPhoneImageSrc = "@../../image/device/iphone.png";
        String ipadImageSrc = "@../../image/device/ipad.png";

        data.clear();
        data.add(new CustomComboBox(smartPhoneImageSrc, "Smart Phone"));
        data.add(new CustomComboBox(ipadImageSrc, "Ipad"));


        cbxDevices.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<CustomComboBox>, ListCell<CustomComboBox>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<CustomComboBox> call(ListView<CustomComboBox> param) {
                ListCell<CustomComboBox> cell = new ListCell<CustomComboBox>(){
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(CustomComboBox item, boolean btl){
                        super.updateItem(item, btl);
                        if(item != null)
                        {
                            Image img = new Image(item.getImageSrc());
                            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
                            imgView.setFitHeight(48);
                            imgView.setFitWidth(48);
                            setGraphic(imgView);
                            setText(item.getString());
                        }
                    }
                };

                return cell;
            }


        });
        cbxDevices.setItems(data);
        //cbxDevices.setButtonCell();  how can i use this methode????



    }




}
```

And this is my class `CustomComboBox`:

```
public class CustomComboBox {

    private String imageSrc;
    private String string;

    public CustomComboBox(String imageSrc, String string) {
        this.imageSrc = imageSrc;
        this.string = string;
    }


    public String getImageSrc() {
        return imageSrc;
    }

    public void setImageSrc(String imageSrc) {
        this.imageSrc = imageSrc;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

[My comboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuKwa.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncXfw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a cell to `setButtonCell()`:

```
cbxDevices.setButtonCell(new ListCell<CustomComboBox>(){
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(CustomComboBox item, boolean btl){
        super.updateItem(item, btl);
        if(item != null) {
            Image img = new Image(item.getImageSrc());
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
            imgView.setFitHeight(48);
            imgView.setFitWidth(48);
            setGraphic(imgView);
            setText(item.getString());
        }
    }
});
```

Note that your cell implementation has a bug: if the cell is reused so that it was previously non-empty but is now empty, it won't clear out the text and graphic. You need to deal with all cases (including a null item/empty cell) in the `updateItem()` method. Also, it's better to create the `ImageView` once, and just update it in the `updateItem()` method than to create a new one each time.

Since you use the same `ListCell` implementation twice, it's probably better to use a named inner class instead of an anonymous class, to avoid duplicating code:

```
public class ContentTabPaneController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<CustomComboBox> cbxDevices;

    private final ObservableList<CustomComboBox> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        String smartPhoneImageSrc = "@../../image/device/iphone.png";
        String ipadImageSrc = "@../../image/device/ipad.png";

        data.clear();
        data.add(new CustomComboBox(smartPhoneImageSrc, "Smart Phone"));
        data.add(new CustomComboBox(ipadImageSrc, "Ipad"));


        cbxDevices.setCellFactory(lv -> new CustomComboCell());
        cbxDevices.setButtonCell(new CustomComboCell());
    }

    private static class CustomComboCell extends ListCell<CustomComboBox> {

        private final ImageView imgView ;

        CustomComboCell() {
            imgView = new ImageView();
            imgView.setFitHeight(48);
            imgView.setFitWidth(48);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(CustomComboBox item, boolean btl){
            super.updateItem(item, btl);
            if(item == null) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                Image img = new Image(item.getImageSrc());
                imgView.setImage(img);
                setGraphic(imgView);
                setText(item.getString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```